# ADB full backup restore command stuck on restoring app Clean Master

Tags: adb, backup, restore

I have a full backup file using adb backup command. When I try to restore the full backup file using adb restore command it always displays "Unfortunately Clean Master has stopped working" while restoring the package of Clean Master app `com.cleanmaster.mguard`.

[adb logcat](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1wbe3mllr1i1e4y/logcat.txt?dl=0) - (too long to paste it here)

How can I skip the clean master app package alone while restoring the full backup?

Comment: I'm restoring the full adb backup file after factory resetting. Nothing is installed on my phone. I've cleared all the data and only pre-installed apps are present in my system.

Comment: Other option is to remove the folder having that app's backup inside your backup file. You can use [Android Backup Extractor](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor) to convert `.ab` into `.tar` then remove the folder and then convert back to `.ab`. All instructions are in its README. Needs JRE to run.

Comment: @Firelord The Android Backupk Extractor gives me `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded`. I've raised an issue on the github link https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor/issues/33

Comment: Did you encrypt the backup using a password? That error isn't specific to ABE.

Comment: From the next time, you might wanna consider Izzy's [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar). It takes separate app backup, so you can easily  avoid the one you don't want to restore.

Comment: Thanks @Firelord. Yes, I have encrypted backup file and I'm entering the right password. The backup is 5.69GB and the output .tar file is 6.01GB and I can even open the tar file without any errors. But I'm just not sure I have fully extracted the backup file or some files are skipped due to this error. I've also used Helium to backup my app data. I can use that for individual apps but I also need picture and videos and other stuff from that backup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26468/discussion-between-firelord-and-lucky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the clean master app data from the backup and re-created the `backup.ab` file again using the [Android Backup Extractor](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor/)(ABE). It seems that the backed up file was corrupted and couldn't able to restore it properly. So I suggest to,

- use the adb backup command atleast twice to make sure the backup is fully completed and compare both file are same sized ones

  ( OR )
- extract the backup file using ABE as .tar export and make sure the extracted `.tar` file can be opened without any errors.

Since I also had app backups using [Helium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup)(Carbon) app, I was able to restore my app data using the Helium app. And all the `shared` data folder contents I moved from the extracted .tar file to my device via an USB cable manually.